# How to convert a section (with subsections etc.) into a chapter?

Tags: sectioning, texstudio

I need to change the structure of my scrbook-document. I want some sections to become chapters and the other way round. But because there are already subsections and subsubsections in the document, I don't want to do this manually. Is there an easier way?

I am using TeXstudio.

**Sample:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\subsection{Should be a chapter}
\subsubsection{Some more info}
\subsubsubection{another layer}
\subsubsection{Still stuff to say}
\end{document}
```

should become

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Now is a chapter}
\subsection{Some more info}
\subsubsection{another layer}
\subsection{Still stuff to say}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is possible to swap the definitions using, for example, \let\chapter=\section.  But keeping them straight?  I would rather use a "change all in selected" editor command.

Comment: That might be the best way, still takes quite some time because you need to replace every level extra but better than doing it completely manually.